# Too tidious hooks when querying in REST. Any ideas?

Tags: feathersjs

I've just started using feathers to build REST server. I need your help for querying tips. Document says

> When used via REST URLs all query values are strings. Depending on the service the values in params.query might have to be converted to the right type in a before hook. (https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/querying.html)

, which puzzles me. `find({query: {value: 1} })` does mean `value === "1"` not `value === 1` ? Here is example client side code which puzzles me:

```
const feathers = require('@feathersjs/feathers')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const restCli = require('@feathersjs/rest-client')
const rest = restCli('http://localhost:8888')
const app = feathers().configure(rest.fetch(fetch))
async function main () {
  const Items = app.service('myitems')
  await Items.create( {name:'one', value:1} )

  //works fine. returns [ { name: 'one', value: 1, id: 0 } ]
  console.log(await Items.find({query:{ name:"one" }}))

  //wow!  no data returned. []
  console.log(await Items.find({query:{ value:1 }})) // []
}
main()
```

Server side code is here:

```
const express = require('@feathersjs/express')
const feathers = require('@feathersjs/feathers')
const memory = require('feathers-memory')
const app = express(feathers())
            .configure(express.rest())
            .use(express.json())
            .use(express.errorHandler())
            .use('myitems', memory())
app.listen(8888)
.on('listening',()=>console.log('listen on 8888'))
```

I've made hooks, which works all fine but it is too tidious and I think I missed something. Any ideas?

Hook code:

```
app.service('myitems').hooks({
  before: { find:  async (context) => {
    const value = context.params.query.value
    if (value) context.params.query.value = parseInt(value)
    return context
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour depends on the database and ORM you are using. Some that have a schema (like `feathers-mongoose`, `feathers-sequelize` and `feathers-knex`), will convert values like that automatically.

Feathers itself does not know about your data format and most adapters (like the `feathers-memory` you are using here) do a strict comparison so they will have to be converted. The usual way to deal with this is to create some reusable hooks (instead of one for each field) like this:

```
const queryToNumber = (...fields) => {
  return context => {
    const { params: { query = {} } } = context;

    fields.forEach(field => {
      const value = query[field];
      if(value) {
        query[field] = parseInt(value, 10)
      }
    });
  }
}

app.service('myitems').hooks({
  before: {
    find: [
      queryToNumber('age', 'value')
    ]
  }
});
```

Or using something like [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/) e.g. through the [validateSchema common hook](https://feathers-plus.github.io/v1/feathers-hooks-common/#validateschema).